# extJs 7.0.0 Community Edition - install docs not working

Tags: extjs

I'm on mac.
Following the guide here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/getting_started/mobile_desktop_application/getting_started_with_npm.html

I signed up for to the community edition, received the mail, created my sencha.myget.org account, and did the following commands successfully in a terminal:

step 1: login to npm repo

```
npm login --registry=https://sencha.myget.org/F/community/npm/ --scope=@sencha
```

step 2: install app generator cli

```
npm install -g @sencha/ext-gen
```

step 3: generate the app

```
ext-gen app -a
```

Now step 4 (run the new application) is where I have a problem:

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

Gives me this error:
[image]

If I open the log I can see the exception message:

```
/Users//Desktop/test/extjs/my-app/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/plugin.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/me/Desktop/test/extjs/my-app/build.xml:15: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So this is how I did it on mac 10.14.

Ok, so reading about javax, apparently it was used in java se8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).

So, I downloaded it using this website: https://adoptopenjdk.net/,
and more precisely this page: https://adoptium.net/?variant=openjdk8.

Once downloaded, I had multiple versions of java installed on my computer and so I had to switch to that one.

So I learned how to switch to any java versions.
First to display the existing versions, type this in the terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Then to change version:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

(notice that for the version number you just type the first two digits, not the whole version number )

To check that it worked:

```
java -version
```

Once java 1.8 (apparently that's the version name for jdk8) was running, the npm start command worked without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade Java to any version less than 15, because the Nashorn JavaScript Engine had been removed, which it depends upon. Downgrading Java as far as version 8 probably isn't the optimum (in particular, when also using it for Java development).